# Extending a solution for simple binding to a 'Text property to multiple Controls to handle binding to any Type?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, controls, extension-methods

*My question is* : how to move beyond writing a custom implementation of a technique for databinding multiple controls (controls without built-in DataSource properties), *for each possible type of data*, to simple properties ... *as described and demonstrated in code that follows* ... to achieve a more poweful solution that will be independent of whether the binding is to a string, or an int, or other types.

My guess is: this will involve reflection; but, I'm stuck at that point. I'm looking for strategic advice on which "direction" to move next, hints, clues, not a complete code answer, but of course I appreciate all responses, and I'll sure study code if you post code in reply ! Marc Clifton's 2005 article on CodeProject [Simple Databinding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simpledatabinding.aspx): appears to demonstrate a reflection based approach: but, honestly, I do not really grok his code, and, in terms of .NET, 2005 is a *long* time ago.

Background: Partly in response to various SO questions and answers, like: [Update Usercontrol on Three Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300514/how-to-put-one-winforms-user-control-on-three-forms-and-update-all-three-simultan/2300878#2300878): I've evolved a successful technique for databinding text properties of various controls simultaneously to one source defined in a Public class; also been able to "abstract" some of the details of the binding process using a static class that defines one extension method, and two public methods.

I've verifed that TextBoxes on Controls in a "MainForm," TextBoxes on a UserControl on the MainForm, and a TextBox on a second Form opened "independently" (i.e., form2.Parent == null) all update properly (i.e., two-way binding is in effect) from the "DataSource equivalent" public class. Change one: change all.

Code: an instance of this class will supply the target property (theText) for databinding:

```
    public class TextDataBinder
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _theText;

        public string theText
        {
            get { return _theText; }

            // note : if 'setter is declared 'internal : blocks 
            // auto-updating when run-time user modifies consumers
            // but will still allow update via code
            set
            {
                _theText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("theText"));         
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Code: this static class enables hiding some of the binding process complexity, and allows easy binding to multiple controls:

```
    public static class TextBindingExtender
    {
        public static TextDataBinder CurrentDataSource;

        public static void SetCurrentDataSource(TextDataBinder newCurrentDataSource)
        {
            CurrentDataSource = newCurrentDataSource;
        }

        // extension method for Control
        public static void AddTextBinding(this Control theControl, string controlPropertyName, string targetPropertyName)
        {
            theControl.DataBindings.Add(controlPropertyName, CurrentDataSource, targetPropertyName, false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        // bind to all Controls in a List<Control>
        public static void AddTextBindings(List<Control> theControls, string controlPropertyName, string targetPropertyName)
        {
            foreach (Control theControl in theControls)
            {
                theControl.AddTextBinding(controlPropertyName, targetPropertyName);
            }
        }
    }
```

How the above classes are used (in a Form Load event) :

```
    // create a new TextDataBinder
    TextBindingExtender.CurrentDataSource = new TextDataBinder();

    // bind to multiple textboxes, label, on a UserControl, on another Form, etc.
    TextBindingExtender.AddTextBindings(new List<Control> { textBox1, textBox2, userControl11.tb, label1, instanceOfForm2.tb }, "Text", "theText");

    // test assigning some initial text to the bound property
    TextBindingExtender.CurrentDataSource.theText = "some initial text";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends what you want to do; but ultimately common data-binding (for simple properties, done manually) consists of:

- obtaining a property; preferably via `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)[propName]`, giving you an abstraction (`PropertyDescriptor`)
- asking the property if it is read-only (`.IsReadOnly`)
- obtain (or set) the value (`.GetValue()`, `.SetValue()`)
- asking it for a converter to format / parse the value (`.Converter`, `.ConvertFromString()`, `.ConvertToString()`) **THIS is a key bit that means you don't have to worry about what the data type is**
- asking it for the caption (`.DisplayName`, or `.Name` if that it empty/null)
- asking it if it supports property-specific notification (`.SupportsChangeEvents`)
- asking it to add/remove a change handler (`.AddValueChanged()`, `.RemoveValueChanged()`)
- you might also want to look at whether the *object* supports centralised notification (look for `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

If you might be binding to a *list* rather than a single object:
 - the list might be abstracted behind `IListSource`
 - the list might have custom properties, so check for `ITypedList`
 - otherwise, identify the `Type` of the items and use `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type)`
 - you need to consider a "currency manager" (i.e. should all the things bound to the same list be pointing to the same record in the list all the time)

There are also things like `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and `TypeDescriptionProvider` to consider, but most of the time `TypeDescriptor` handles this for you automatically.

As you can see - lots of things to think about! Lots of work... the one thing that you *don't* have to do is reflection; this is abstracted behind `PropertyDescriptor`. The reason for this is that not all data is static-typed; think about `DataTable` - the columns (which map to bindable data properties) are not fixed at compile-time, so reflection isn't appropriate. Likewise, some other types have custom "property bag" implementations. `PropertyDescriptor` lets your code handle either dynamic (not in the 4.0 sense) and reflective properties identically. It also works nicely with things like "HyperDescriptor", another property customisation.

Comment: Thanks, Marc, Very valuable "pointers" and ideas: I have some learning "ahead of me." :)