# How can I get the value from a combobox

Tags: c#, database, combobox, oledb

I can't get the value from a combobox. My objective is that when I select an item in the combobox it shows the address of the customer in the `txtadres` textbox.

When I test the code it gives a null reference exception.

I also tried `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` but that didn't work either. I can't use `comboBox1.Text` because the display member is different than the value member. The display member is the customer name and the value member is the customer code.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{           
    string cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Database1.accdb";           
    string cc = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();          
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE customercode = '" + cc + "'";

    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cs))  
    {

        if (cc == "")
        {
            txtadres.Text = "No address found!";
        }
        else
        {
            OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            OleDbDataReader DB = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (!DB.Read())
                return;

            txtadres.Text = DB["Adress"].ToString();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** I found the sollution, this worked for me: `string cc = Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue);`

Comment: Your problem is more to do with how you are populating the combo box, [this answer should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2424060/838807)

Comment: Outside of your issues with retrieving the selected item, you should NOT be using inline SQL.  This poses a pretty serious security risk, even if you're using WinForms instead of WebForms.  Your best bet is to accept the value and pass it into paramaterized stored procedures, unless you'd like to use some form of ORM.

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectedItem` in a combobox is a `ListBoxItem`, and is described on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx).

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.aspx) has much more information on the methods and properties of a ListBoxItem.

In short, though, to access the text of the SelectedItem, you will use code like the following:

```
string itemText = (comboBox1.SelectedItem.Content).ToString();
```

If your ComboBox items aren't just text, this will return the selected object (as whatever class it is).  If it IS just a string, this will get you that string.

Remember, though, that `SelectedItem` can be null, so you should do null checks on it before using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where to start with this problem to be honest, but the first major issue here is that your making a connection to the Database on every index change and that's a fundamental no no.

You need to look at using a Data Adapter to populate the contents of your database query into a DataTable object. You can then set the datasource for your combo box to the DataTable.

From here, you can assign the Display & Value members for the combo box and capture the selected value on Index changed without making any calls to the database.

It's really a matter of rethinking your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar frustrations with combo boxes. This probably isn't the best, but this is what I did:

((ComboBoxItem)ComboBox.SelectedItem).CustomerCode;

Replace the ComboBoxItem cast with whatever object you filled the combobox with.
Of course, this only works if you filled the combo box with the item your trying to access.